# SharePoint Column Formula Validation

Tags: 2013, list, column, validation, calculated-column-formula

I need to check if a column (type Number) is an Integer (no decimal).
I added this formula to the list validation:

```
=mod([MyField],1)=0
```

But I get this error:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your separator is not "," but ";". It depends on the regional settings.
  You can try your formula like this

```
=mod([MyField];1)<>0
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula:

```
=MOD([MyField],1)=0
```